# TelerikChart Width

Tags: telerik, blazor, telerik-charting

Is there a way to make a TelerikChart which nested inside TileLayoutItem to be 100% width of the Content?

Following isn't working, (the chart is being cut at the right end)

```
<TileLayoutItem ColSpan="2" RowSpan="2">
    <Content>           
        <TelerikChart Width="100%" Height="100%">
            <ChartSeriesItems>
                <ChartSeries Type="ChartSeriesType.Line" Name="Completed" Data="@_clientDuration">
                </ChartSeries>
            </ChartSeriesItems>

            <ChartValueAxes>
                <ChartValueAxis Color="red"></ChartValueAxis>
            </ChartValueAxes>

            <ChartCategoryAxes>
                <ChartCategoryAxis Categories="@_xAxisItems"></ChartCategoryAxis>
            </ChartCategoryAxes>
        </TelerikChart>
    </Content>
</TileLayoutItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work like that unless some more CSS from the web site is breaking things. Also, when the tiles resize you may want to `.Refresh()` the chart.

The provided snippet runs fine for me when I run it in the boilerplate project template and I add some dummy data, and the same scenario runs in [this demo](https://demos.telerik.com/blazor-ui/tilelayout/overview) as well.

Thus, the issue is probably related to something specific in the project and if comparing against the demo or a blank project does not help I think the better approach is to contact the Telerik support.